# does the javascript spec guaratee that all built-in static methods can be called as functions (without the receiver)

Tags: javascript

For example, Array.from is referred to as a method, but Array.isArray, as a function

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-array-constructor

in practice both are callable as functions (`const arrFrom = Array.from; arrFrom('string');`), but does the spec guarantee this for all static built-ins or some or none?

Comment: @mhodges Neither `isArray` nor `from` live on `Array.prototype`.

Comment: @Bergi You're right, I misspoke

Comment: By **in practice both are callable as functions**, do you mean **both are callable both as method and as function, without an observable difference in effect**? That's a subtle but quite important distinction.

Comment: I meant without difference, but yes, looking at the spec for Array.form, it does switch on `this` so there's going to be some difference/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no guarantees. It's different for every static method.

For any given built-in static method, lookup its specification, and **if it does not refer to `this`, it's a function**.

- [`Object`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-object-constructor): none of the static `Object` methods rely on their receiver, they don't use the `Object` constructor but just operate on their arguments or create a new plain object.
- [`Function`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-function-constructor), [`GeneratorFunction`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-generatorfunction-constructor), [`AsyncFunction`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-async-function-constructor-properties), [`Boolean`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-boolean-constructor), [`Error`s](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-nativeerror-constructors), [`RegExp`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-regexp-constructor), [`Map`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-map-constructor), [`WeakMap`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-weakmap-constructor), [`Set`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-set-constructor), [`WeakSet`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-weakset-constructor), [`SharedArrayBuffer`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-sharedarraybuffer-constructor), [`DataView`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-dataview-constructor): none of these constructors contains any static methods
- [`Symbol`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-symbol-constructor): none of the static `Symbol` methods rely on their receiver, they don't use the `Symbol` constructor
- [`Number`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-number-constructor), [`Date`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-date-constructor): none of their static methods rely on their receiver, they just operate on their arguments and return a primitive number.
- [`String`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-string-constructor): none of the static `String` methods rely on their receiver, they don't use the `String` constructor but just operate on their arguments and return a primitive string.
- [`Array`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-array-constructor):

  - [`isArray`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-array.isarray) just returns a boolean
  - [`from`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-array.from), [`of`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-array.of): these *do* rely on their receiver value, but when it's not a constructor function they fall back on the default `Array`. This is probably for backwards compatibility to when `Array` was not extensible.
- Typed arrays: they don't have static methods [on their own](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-typedarray-constructors), but inherit them from a [common intrinsic object](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-%25typedarray%25-intrinsic-object)

  - [`from`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-%25typedarray%25.from), [`of`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-%25typedarray%25.of): these *do* rely on their receiver value to be a constructor that returns a typed array
- [`ArrayBuffer`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-arraybuffer-constructor):

  - `isView` just returns a boolean
- [`Math`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-function-properties-of-the-math-object), [`Atomics`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-atomics-object), [`JSON`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-json-object), [`Reflect`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-reflect-object): they're not constructors anyway, their "methods" are just namespaced functions that do not rely on their receiver
- [`Promise`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-promise-constructor):

  - [`all`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-promise.all), [`race`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-promise.race), [`reject`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-promise.reject), [`resolve`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-promise.resolve): these *do* rely on their receiver value to be a constructor that works like `Promise`
- [`Proxy`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-proxy-constructor) is not really designed to be subclassable, it wouldn't even need to be a constructor.

  - `revocable`: does not rely on its receiver

So in general most of the static "methods" are just namespaced functions, ignoring their receiver completely. There are however a few methods which return *instances* of the constructor they are invoked on, most notably promise and (typed) array methods, which do require the respective receiver. `Object` and `Array` are exceptions to this.

Comment: You appear to be saying it's guaranteed for some built-ins and not others, please point to such a guarantee in the spec.

Comment: Thanks for the added detail, but where's the spec reference?  I am not asking about implementations, nor for an opinion, but a definitive specification of the "methods" being functions.

Comment: @Alex You just have to read the spec for the respective function and check whether it uses the `this` value, i.e. whether it's a method or not.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that if the abstract method description in the spec does not refer to `this` that's a guarantee of it being a function.  Makes sense.