# Principle behind short callback function syntax

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming

What is the principle behind this?
`newArr.some(Array.isArray)` ===  `newArr.some(elem => Array.isArray(elem))`

How is posible that they are parsed as equal?
I thought that `newArr.some(Array.isArray)` ===  `newArr.some(Array.isArray())` (assuming that `some` is a loop and that JS assumed each val as the implicit arg of the func),  but it's not. So, I'm confused. Please, help me.

Here, there are 2 applications of the cases above:

```
function flatMultiArr(arr) {
let newArr = [].concat(...arr);
return newArr.some(Array.isArray)
? flatMultiArr(newArr)
: newArr
}

console.log();//[ 1, {}, 3, 4 ]
```

```
function flatMultiArr(arr) {
let newArr = [].concat(...arr);
return newArr.some(elem => Array.isArray(elem))
? flatMultiArr(newArr)
: newArr
}

console.log();//[ 1, {}, 3, 4 ]
```

Note this question is not about how to flatten multidimentional arrays.

Comment: `.some` takes a callback function. You can pass a function directly in, or wrap it in an anonymous function. It's the same thing more or less. `arr.some(e => (e => Array.isArray(e))(e))` works too--you can just keep adding layers of indirection for no reason.

Comment: "I thought that `newArr.some(Array.isArray) === newArr.some(Array.isArray())`" No, absolutely not. `newArr.some(Array.isArray())` isn't passing a callback at all, rather, the result of calling the function which is supposed to be used as a callback, which probably doesn't work. A callback is a *function*, so you need to pass the function, i.e. `Array.isArray`, not the *result of calling the function*, `Array.isArray()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This principle is known as [eta conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eta_conversion#%CE%B7-reduction). No, they are not "parsed as equal", they are different functions, but they *behave the same*, and therefore can be reasoned about equally. To simplify:

```
const f = Array.isArray
```

and

```
function f(x) { return Array.isArray(x); }
```

will have the same results when called<sup>1</sup>, i.e. `f([])` or `f(5)`.

<sub>1: In general, there are minor differences wrt to [the `this` binding in the method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572) and the number of arguments, but [it works for `Array.isArray`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47912363/1048572)</sub>.

Comment: Thanks Bergi. I was useful the reference to calculus. I' getting material in that area to improve my functional programming

Answer (score 2):

Please note that callbacks are just functions. It is called eta-abstraction and makes your function slightly more lazy:

```js
const fix  = f =>      f(fix( f));
const fix_ = f => x => f(fix_(f)) (x);
//                ^^^^            ^^^ eta abstraction

try {
const map = fix(go => f => ([x, ...xs]) =>
    x == undefined
      ? []
      : go(f) (xs).concat(f(x)));
}

catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}

const map_ = fix_(go => f => ([x, ...xs]) =>
    x === undefined
      ? []
      : [f(x)].concat(go(f) (xs)));

console.log(
  map_(x => x * x) ([1,2,3]));
```